# Office 365 Developer Account and access to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office

After setup, and accessing my Admin Tab I can see Purchase Services. €4.10 I think stated per month for access to various Apps including SharePoint Plan 1. Is SharePoint also available as a free trial to accompany the Office 365 Developer Account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You have a year in Office Dev tenant, but you don't get a license. But you can work with SharePoint in a Dev tenant

Sign up here for free: https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizardnp.aspx?wizid=14b845d0-938c-45af-b061-f798fbb4d170&lcid=1033

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did complete that form with the relevant information. For access to SharePoint under the Office 365 Admin>>Subscriptions I selected the 30 day Free Trial for Microsoft Office 365 Developer. While there is an option to extend this trial which I will look at I am assuming this is for a short time period as well. Question - do I need to commit to paying the €8.10 for continued access to my SharePoint Online environment?